# Border bottom on anchor tags, which works on multiple lines and with inline block / block display

Tags: css, anchor

I have some anchor tags across my site that I need to have a 'custom' underline according to the design.

The issue is that when the link text breaks to multiple lines the bottom border only applies to the bottom line / the bottom of anchor. I can solve this by giving the anchor links a display of inline, but then I lose the ability to give them a margin top.

Is there any way I can give links a underline of 2px and works across multiple lines whilst also being able to give them a margin top?

Example fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mjxfzrwk/

Code just incase:

```css
.custom-underline {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.standard-underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.inline {
  display: inline;
}
.container {
  width: 100px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 29px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="custom-underline" href="">This has a good underline</a> 
  <br/>
  <a class="standard-underline" href="">This has a standard underline</a> 
  <br />
  <a class="custom-underline inline" href="">This has a good underline but display inline removed top margin</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:before` pseudo element like below. [**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/mjxfzrwk/1/)

```
.inline:before{
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also wrap your text inside `span` and apply `border-bottom` to span

```css
a {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
span {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a href=""><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt, quisquam.</span></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well for color you can use this

```
a{
    text-decoration: underline;
    -moz-text-decoration-color: red; /* Code for Firefox */
    text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

But the spacing thing cannot be done with `text-decoration:underline`

Answer (score 0):

use display inline method as the last option in your code and then try adding below styles in your css

```
.inline:before{
     content: " ";
     height:20px;
     display: block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a multiline border for your text you need 2 things:

1. Set these 3 CSS properties for your element

   ```
   .custom-underline {
       border-bottom: 2px solid red;
       display: inline;
       text-decoration: none;
   }
   ```
2. Check the `display` property for the **parent** of your element. Some `display` values will break the multiline behavior of its child. For example, values `block`, `flow`, `inline`, `table` WILL work, but values `flex`, `inline-flex`, `grid` and `inline-grid` WILL NOT work. And surprise: `display: none` will not work too :)

Then you won't be able to change inline element's vertical position using `margin`/`padding`/`transform + translateY` etc. But you can increase `line-height`. If it doesn't work for you, you can set `margin` or `padding` for the parent element.